# Using jQuery or JavaScript to sort a table in Ascending or Descending Order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

I have a table, and I want to sort the table according to input from a selectbox (the dropdown `id="bil"`), in ascending or descending order of dates.

```js
var itemsAscend = [];
var itemsDescend = [];
$('#bil').on('change', function() {
  var itemsAscend1 = [];
  itemsAscend = itemsAscend1;
  var itemsDescend1 = [];
  itemsDescend = itemsDescend1;
  $('#tabbody tr td:nth-child(2)').each(function() {
    //add item to array
    itemsAscend.push($(this).text());
    itemsDescend.push($(this).text());
  });

  itemsAscend.sort((d1, d2) => new Date(d1) - new Date(d2) > 0);
  itemsDescend.sort((d1, d2) => new Date(d1) - new Date(d2) < 0);
 
  
  var selectedValue = this.value;
  $('#tabbody tr').hide();

  // var selects = itemsAscend;
  // var selects1 = itemsDescend;
  // console.log(selects)
  // console.log(itemsAscend.reverse())
  if (selectedValue === "Ascend") {
    for (var i = 0; i < itemsAscend.length; i++) {
      $(itemsAscend[i]).parents('tr').show();
    }
  } else if (selectedValue === "Descend") {
    for (var i = 0; i < itemsDescend.length; i++) {
      $(itemsDescend[i]).parents('tr').show();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <div>
    <select class="form-control" id="bil" style="">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="Ascend">Ascend</option>
      <option value="Descend" selected="">Descend</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>S.NO</th>
        <th>Date</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tabbody">
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>01-Oct-15</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>01-Jan-16</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>20-Jun-17</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>05-Dec-17</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

I have tried using the above code, but am not getting the desired result.

Comment: Have you talked to a rubber duck recently? https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: What exactly does "no result" mean? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: You should put the `<script>` element inside the `<body>`, not after it.

Comment: You have `new Date(d1)` it should be `new Date(d1).getTime()`, and `new Date(d2).getTime()`

Comment: I am trying to sort table according to input from selectbox(ie: Ascend or Descend) and trying to sort table row in ascending order of table row of dates or descending order of table row of dates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Date` object to parse dates but you also need to remove `-` then just check value from select and sort by that order.

```js
$('select').change(function() {
 var order = $(this).val();
  
  var sorted = $('tbody tr').sort(function(a, b) {
    var a = new Date($(a).find('td:last-child').text().split('-').join(' '));
    var b = new Date($(b).find('td:last-child').text().split('-').join(' '));

    return order == 'desc' ?  b - a : a - b;
  })

  $('tbody').html(sorted)
  
  $("tr").each(function(i) {
    $(this).find('td:first-child').text(i)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select class="form-control" id="bil" style="">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="asc">Ascend</option>
    <option value="desc" selected="">Descend</option>
  </select>
</div>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>S.NO</th>
      <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tabbody">
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>20-Jun-17</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>01-Oct-15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>01-Jan-16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>05-Dec-17</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: See update, after each change you can loop tr and set numbers.